# Are all four SO-DIMM slots user-accessible in the 27 inch iMac (Late 2012)?

Tags: imac, memory

I'm going to buy a new 27" iMac, but I think that the RAM on the Apple Store is really too expensive.

My plan is to buy with minimum (2x4GB) RAM and replace everything with 4x8GB.

Are **all 4 slots** designed to be user accessible, removable and replaceable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Tech Specs](http://www.apple.com/uk/imac/specs/) page on the Apple site states:

> 8GB (two 4GB) of 1600MHz DDR3 memory; four user-accessible SO-DIMM
> slots
>
> Configurable to 16GB or 32GB.

so yes, all four slots are user accessible.

Comment: Yeah I think it's only the 21" iMac that "forces" you to buy the RAM from Apple (RAM slots under the logic board or something like that).